# Erro de carregamento de maps com a api google maps

Tags: javascript, aplicação-web, maps

Estou trabalhando em um projeto web que utiliza a api maps, contudo, em alguns momentos, o sistema retorna com o seguinde erro e o mapa não abri:

> Uncaught Eb message: "initMap is not a function"name: "InvalidValueError"stack: "Error↵    at new Eb

Em outros momentos, o mapa abre normalmente. Alguém têm ideia do que pode está ocorrendo e como posso resolver? No meu script não tem nenhuma variável com o nome Eb.

No HTML eu defino uma div que vai carregar o mapa

```
<div id="map" class="pull-right"></div>
```

Dai eu importo o mapa

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=??????=places&callback=initMap"
async defer></script>
```

E defino a função initMap num script na mesma página do htlm.

```
function initMap(){
        // Definição do ponte de inicialização do mapa
        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-5.843470, -36.619855);

        // Definição das configurações visuais do mapa
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            center: myLatLng,
            styles: [
                { 
                    featureType: 'road',
                    elementType: 'all',
                    stylers:[{visibility: 'off'}]
                },
                {
                    featureType: 'water',
                    elementType: 'all',
                    stylers:[{color: '#ffffff'}]
                },
                {
                    featureType: 'landscape',
                    elementType: 'all',
                    stylers:[{color: '#ffffff'}]
                }
            ]
        }

        // Instanciando o mapa com as configurações defidas dentro de uma div cujo id está especificado na instrução
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),mapOptions);   
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
}
```

Dentro do script existe outras definições de variáveis e função. No entanto adicionei apenas esta por ser a que vai inicializar o mapa. Dentro da função initMap também está definido varios poligonos e os eventos de cada poligono.

Comment: Coloca o código ai pra gente te ajudar, de preferencia seu HTML e Javascript.

Comment: Adicionei mais informaçõs do problema. Da uma olhada por favor. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A API do Google Maps não encontrou a função "initMap()", pois ela deve ter carregado antes, devido ao atributo "async". Tente retirar esse atributo pra ver se resolve. Caso não resolva, defina a função antes da chamada da API. Veja alguns pontos importantes também abaixo:

1. Defina o carregamento da API no final do `<body>` e arrume a chamada, pois está errado `?key=??????=places&callback=initMap`. Os parâmetros são formados por chave e valor, como por exemplo: *callback* (chave) e *initMap* (valor). Porém o valor "places", você não definiu a chave, que é "libraries". Ficando correto assim: `?key=??????&libraries=places&callback=initMap`.
2. Crie sua função "initMap()" antes do carregamento da API, como no exemplo que eu fiz no [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/rotonibire/edit?html,css,js,output).

Comment: Deu certo. Coloquei o carregamento da API no final do <body>, depois da definição da função initMap e funcionou. Não ta mais retornando erro. 

Resolvido. Valeu....

Comment: Opa, maravilha. Marca a resposta como correta fazendo favor. Obrigado.